# Make a button in the body of the email to send info back to the sender of the email

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

I recently started using MS Outlook 2007 but am having trouble understanding how I could implement something specific. To get to the point, this is what I'd like to know how to do:
How could I create/store controls or visual elements such as buttons, textboxes, etc..?
 How could I allow the person who receives the email then input info into the text box inside the email, then also inside the email, locally store the data from the text box control ao that it could be edited and returned?
How could I then receive an email when the person clicks something inside of the email?

 Is something like this even possible? Thank you for giving my questions a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not run scripts in HTML emails. Forms are also a no-no.