# Get an automatic email when someone clicked on a link in my Outlook email

Tags: vba, outlook

This is my first time using Outlook's VBA so I'm not sure if this is possible. What I'm looking to do is send an email with links in the email body.

When a user clicks on the link, I would like to get an automatic reply so that I can track my engagement. I looked at this similar question - [Want to trigger Automate reply after click on a link in Outlook mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44696333/want-to-trigger-automate-reply-after-click-on-a-link-in-outlook-mail) to get inspired for a solution but it wasn't an exact fit. Thank you so much for your help on this!

```
Sub MailURL()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    strbody = "<HTML><BODY>"
    strbody = strbody & "<a href=""mailto: omar@omar.com"">Relpy here</a>"
    strbody = strbody & "</BODY></HTML>"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "omar@omar.com"
        .Subject = "Testing URL"
        .HTMLBody = strbody
       ' .Send
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you thought about "Request a delivery receipt" or "Request a read request"? They don't work with all email packages and typically the receiver can choose not to send them but they might be better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like that. If there was a way, that would be a huge security hole.

The best you can do is have a mailto link that will display a new message (but the user would still have to click Send). Or you can have a link to your own website, where you can record the hit.